# How To Prevent Fast Execute Many Giving Truncation Error

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas

Not sure how to reproduce this as I'm not sure what is causing the issue in the first place, however, I have the currently line of code which writes data to an SQL Server Table.

```
dbEngine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(constring, fast_executemany=True) 

try:
    df_to_sql.to_sql(table_name, con=dbEngine, schema='dbo', if_exists='append', index=False, chunksize=50)
except:
    df_from_sql = pd.read_sql(f'SELECT * FROM {table_name}', engine)
    new_data = pd.concat([df_from_sql, df_to_sql])
    new_data.to_sql(table_name, con=dbEngine, schema='dbo', if_exists='replace', index=False, chunksize=50)
```

However I get the following error:

```
('String data, right truncation: length 1000 buffer 510', 'HY000')
```

I have checked the sql server and see that varchar has been set to -1 which indicates that the field is of max length? Any idea what could be causing this?

Cheers

Comment: Passing the table name to a query like indicates a major design flaw.

Comment: It's not something that a person can input into the query. It's a hardcoded value that I use from a specific dictionary lookup. Therefore, there is no user input into the query directly.

Comment: Glad to hear there isn't a sql injection possibility. But still using select * and passing in the table screams of things going a bit the wrong way.

Comment: Hmmm, it was mainly my way of dealing with a new column when writing different files to a database. I wasn't sure how quite to insert the columns straight in and found selecting all and replacing the table seemed to work. Any improvement would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was I was using an incorrect engine and not replacing the table everytime a new column was found. Changing the engine fixed this and now everything writes to the database as required.